# Implementation of "Localization from Incomplete Noisy Distance Measurements" paper

Tags: matlab, cvx

I would like to mention that I am new in CVX community. So, my doubt might be stupid. As I could not figure out the problem of my code, I have decided to post it here. I am trying to implement an algorithm as stated in the paper, titled as-

> Localization from Incomplete Noisy Distance Measurements. [(Link of the paper)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10208-012-9129-5)

In case the paper is not accessible I am also uploading a snapshot of the algorithm in my : [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXN5vAP3Ux6TFZXb2daTUdMcDQ/view?usp=sharing)

I am dealing with a complete graph in a noiseless scenario. So according to the theory, I should get the perfect reconstruction. But it is not giving me the correct result, and the error value is quite high.

The code written by me is as follows-

```html
    % E: n-by-n matrix where (i,j)th element represents the distance between ith and jth node
    % N: Number of nodes
    % d: dimension of the space where nodes are embedded
    %% Calling CVX Package
    Q = zeros(N,N);
    Mij = zeros(N,N);
    cvx_precision best;
    cvx_begin
    variable Q(N,N) semidefinite                       % Defining variables
    minimize(trace(Q))                                 % Objective function
    subject to
    % Constraints
    for i = 1:N-1
        for j = i:N
            if E(i,j) ~= 0
                Mij = Mij-Mij;
                Mij(i,j) = -1;
                Mij(j,i) = -1;
                Mij(i,i) = 1;
                Mij(j,j) = 1;
                trace(Mij*Q) == square_pos(E(i,j));
            end
        end
    end
    cvx_end
    [U,S,~] = svd(Q);
    X_est = U(:,1:d)*sqrt(S(1:d,1:d));
    X_est = X_est';
```

The algorithm SDP-based Algorithm for Localization